# Will this log4j.properties content would be suited for Production Environment

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We will be moving our Application in production .

For this , We have added log4j support to the Application .

I have got this log4j.properties file  from  internet , and i put this file inside the classes folder of my Web Application .

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is a DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.file=/MyWebApplication.log
log4j.appender.A1.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.append=true
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%t] %l %C{5}:%M - %m%n
```

Is the above properties file suitable for a high-volume website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> iS the above properties file would be suited for a High volume website

No, not really.  You'll set all logging to `DEBUG` level, which is likely to generate vast amounts of logging (especially if you use 3rd-party libraries such as Spring or Hibernate). Not only will this make your logs difficult to read, it may also serious impact performance (log4j doesn't actually perform well under high load and concurrency, it's full of `synchronized` blocks).

I suggest you turn your logging down to `INFO`, and perhaps even `WARN`.

Answer (score 2):

**Absolutely not.**

In addition to being at the DEBUG level, you're using the `%l`, `%M`, and `%C` format specifiers, which are *documented* to be "extremely slow".

See the [`PatternLayout` docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).